# How to catch Tab keystroke in input? (ncurses)

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm using ncurses and I'm getting input string with `getstr()`. I want to make something like autocompletion by Tab keystroke. However, I don't see a way to catch Tab with `getstr()`. I tried this:

```
char input = 0;
while (input != '\n')
    switch (input = getch())
    {
        case '\t':
            printw("Got Tab\n");
            break;
        default:
            addch(input);
            break;
    }
```

But in this case I have to write my own handlings for Backspace, Delete etc., what is undesirable and essentialy is reinventing of wheel.

Comment: There are a few higher-level libraries which purport to do event-handling, but none are well supported.  Someone's certain to mention one (or mention something in the same general area).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
 switch (input = getch())
 {
     case KEY_STAB:
         printw("Got Tab\n");
         break;
     default:
         addch(input);
         break;
 }
```

[Complete list of keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/Getting-characters-from-the-keyboard.html)

Comment: No, I'm not about this. '\t' works correctly. I'm interested in the possibility of getting '\t' without losing ncurses handlings for keys like Backspace

Comment: What you want is not going to happen, sorry. There is no such possibility. If you want to do character-by-character processing, you have to use character-by-character input functions.

Answer (score 1):

This one works fine for me:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char input = 0;
    while (input != '\n') {
        input = getch();
        switch (input)
        {
            case '\t':
                printf("T");
                break;
            case '\b':
                printf("\b \b");
                break;
            default:
                printf("%c", input);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

using the latest `g++`

Comment: Do you compile it as *c* or *c++*

Comment: No, I'm not about this. I'm interested in getting '\t' without losing default handlings for keys like Backspace

Comment: there are platform specific solutions. if you don't mind. what is your target platform?

Comment: Linux. However I think it is important that I use ncurses, because I shouldn't use standard terminal input/output functions with it

Comment: how about "reinvent" backspace as well.

Comment: If I won't find a more suitting solution, I think I will have to do it